# Flex Table in GWT

Tags: gwt, flextable

i want a table in gwt, which is used to update the database..
since the table is a updater of database, i need add, edit, remove and save commands..
The project is being created for internal purpose of the company, so I look for a solution that does not require commercial licensing for such uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Web Toolkit Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/) project has a [`PagingScrollTable`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PagingScrollTable) which seems to fit your requirements. Check out the the [demo](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/demo/com.google.gwt.gen2.demo.scrolltable.PagingScrollTableDemo/PagingScrollTableDemo.html) too.

Comment: thanks.. it is very useful.. i'll contact u if i have any queries

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/). The license fits your needs and has a Grid component with all the requested features.